# Why can't I pair my BLE device?

Tags: c#, winforms, bluetooth-lowenergy

This is my code for pairing.

```
var Name = listBox1.SelectedItem as BluetoothLEDeviceDisplay;
          DevicePairingResult result = await Name.DeviceInformation.Pairing.PairAsync();
          updateUI("Paired.");
```

I setup my "Name" to discover my ble devices.

```
private void OnAdvertisementReceived(BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher watcher, BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {

      Name = eventArgs.Advertisement.LocalName;
      if (items.Contains(Name) == false)
      {
        items.Add(Name);
      }

    }
```

When I try to pair the BLE device(rfduino). I Get error `"<Name>5_1 is null"`. How do I solve this?

Comment: `"5_1 is null"` Which exact line throws that exception?

Comment: It just keels over with a NullReferenceException because the LocalName property is null.  Hard to guess why, but consider to add `if (Name != null) { ... }` to get ahead.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you don't have to pair  your device.
Most, if not all Ble-devices don't need pairing, unless you want a pairing dialog for entering pin-number.

Your code makes no sense at all.
BluetoothLEDeviceDisplay is a separate class containing objects and enums for easy display,
used in some UWP example.
It is not your Ble-device!
So Name as a selected item will always be null.
If you have added this class to your project use Custom pairing:

```
DeviceInformationCustomPairing customPairing = bleDeviceDisplay.DeviceInformation.Pairing.Custom;
                DevicePairingKinds ceremoniesSelected = DevicePairingKinds.None | DevicePairingKinds.ProvidePin;
                DevicePairingProtectionLevel protectionLevel = DevicePairingProtectionLevel.None;
                customPairing.PairingRequested += new TypedEventHandler<DeviceInformationCustomPairing,
                                                      DevicePairingRequestedEventArgs>(CustomPairing_PairingRequested);
                DevicePairingResult result = await customPairing.PairAsync(ceremoniesSelected,
                                                   protectionLevel);                


        private void CustomPairing_PairingRequested(DeviceInformationCustomPairing sender, DevicePairingRequestedEventArgs args)
        {
            //this is where your pin goes.
            //windows requires at least a "0".
            args.Accept("000000");//123456
        }
```

I used this before the Windows 10 creators update, but after that never again.
Have a look at my Github example to get you going without pairing:
https://github.com/GrooverFromHolland/SimpleBleExample_by_Devicename